# Why fragment is getting added to the back stack several times

Tags: android, fragment, bottomnavigationview

I was trying to implement the bottom navigation with fragment inside an activity.
I have done that and it was successful.

To replace the fragment on click each navigation item, I use the following code.

```
private BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener
        = new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {

    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.navigation_notifications:
                loadFragment(new NotificationsFragment());
                return true;
            case R.id.navigation_notes:
                loadFragment(new NotesFragment());
                return true;
            case R.id.navigation_about:
                loadFragment(new AboutFragment());
                return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
};

private void loadFragment(Fragment fragment) {
    // load fragment
    FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    transaction.replace(R.id.frame_container, fragment);
    transaction.addToBackStack(null);
    transaction.commit();
}
```

Now the problem is that when I click on a navigation in the bottom navigation bar multiple times, the fragment is also getting added to the back stack multiple times.
So when I click the back button the fragment is again loaded, not exiting or loading the previous fragment.

So, How can I prevent the fragment getting added to the back stack multiple times?

Comment: Try to use navigation fragment it has own back stack maintenance.

Comment: Thanks for the response. And is there any other option that I can do with the same code?

Comment: Add Fragment Class Name to addToBackStack

Answer (score 0):

Remove

> transaction.addToBackStack(null);

**or** add

> transaction.disallowAddToBackStack();